# How to delete a custom field in an Apple iCloud development database?

Tags: icloud, apple-developer

I am trying to delete a custom field ("prefix") in an Apple iCloud development database.  When I go to delete the field in the iCloud Dashboard, the red delete button is inactive.
[image]

The schema has been deployed to a production environment, but it is not being used nor is there any data in it.  If necessary, I can delete/remove the production schema.  How can I delete this field (or how can I delete the production environment?).  I do NOT what to lose the data in the development database.